# Infragisitcs ultrawingrid columnchooser and column filters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an Infragistics UltraWinGrid and I'm using its built-in column chooser.

However there is an issue whereby if a user has a filter on a particular column, then hides that column, the filter is still applied to the data.

I would expect that if the column is hidden then its filter should no longer apply OR I should at least be able to set this somehow.

I've looked and can't find a way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a column is hidden, the `UltraWinGrid.AfterColPosChanged` event is fired.  The event arguments don't tell you which column has had its position changed (i.e. *hidden*) so the easiest thing to do it iterate over the columns and clear the filters of any hidden columns.

```
private void grid_AfterColPosChanged(object sender, AfterColPosChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UltraGridBand band in grid.DisplayLayout.Bands)
    {
       foreach (ColumnFilter filter in band.ColumnFilters)
       {
            if (filter.Column.Hidden)
            {
                filter.ClearFilterConditions();
            }
       }
   }
{
```

Clunky, but it works.

Answer (score -2):

Handle column hiding; just bind `Column.Hidden` to your object and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to code.. Do you have a specific example with the ultrawingrid? Where do I handle the column hiding? Which event? I can't see the one that gets fired.

Comment: As far I know it's no the event, but the property (.Hidden) is changed when user selects a column in the column chooser, and if you bind the property to your object, you is able to handle showing/hiding columns